# How to ignore multiple inputs when reading from a file?

Tags: c

So currently I have this code that allows me to import words from a text file and store it in to an array, what I would like it to do is ignore any punctuation such as "," - "." - etc.

However I am unable to do so with `%[,]s` or something similar seen below, any help on this please?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
  FILE *myFileHandle;
  myFileHandle = fopen("test1.txt", "r"); 
  char *lineofText;
  if (myFileHandle != NULL){
      while (!feof(myFileHandle)){
          fscanf(myFileHandle, "%[,]s", lineofText);
          puts(lineofText);

      }
  }


  fclose(myFileHandle);
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: well, `fscanf` is not the tool for this. Easier to read just character by character and check if it is to be stored into the array

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Could you guide me to some tool that is able to complete my objective at hand? Thanks

Comment: C is probably the most powerful tool you have, more than capable of your job; you just have to do it yourself. If you want a tool that would make the task *easier*, I suggest Python.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker By a tool I meant a function that can complete the objective I would want it to.

Comment: Yes, the C library doesn't have complex string functions like that; it really doesn't even have a string type. There are non-standard third-party libraries, but they are often quite complicated (as they would have to be in C). Munging of strings is really the strength of languages with garbage collection and real string types.

Comment: Who or what text suggested code like `while (!feof(myFileHandle)){`?

Comment: @IncreasinglyIdiotic Yes.